# FOSMessageBundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, message-bundle

How do i set, when i create a thread, that the message is read by the creator of the thread?

I have this portion of code

```
$composer = $this->get('fos_message.composer');
    $message  = $composer->newThread()
        ->setSender($this->getUser())
        ->setSubject('myThread')
        ->setBody($request->get('createThread')['my_thread']);

    $sender = $this->get('fos_message.sender');
    $sender->send($message);
```

But when i send the message in the last line, in the database the value of is_read is set to 0, when the sender should be set to 1. So, i need to set the author to is read when he send the message.

Anyone? :)

Comment: what entity's propertie is `is_read`?

Comment: is the message_metadata, but i cannot set it directly from message, there is a method for $message->setIsreadbyParticipant, but this method search in the database for the metadata and then set it. I want to set it before the entity persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Message metadata doesn't exist until message is persisted. That's why you have to set read status *after* saving message to database.

The easiest way to do this is registering EventSubscriber.
Working example code:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use FOS\MessageBundle\Event\MessageEvent;
use FOS\MessageBundle\Event\FOSMessageEvents as Event;
use FOS\MessageBundle\ModelManager\MessageManagerInterface;

class MessageSendSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $messageManager;

    public function __construct(MessageManagerInterface $messageManager)
    {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            Event::POST_SEND => 'markAsReadBySender'
        );
    }

    public function markAsReadBySender(MessageEvent $event)
    {
        $message = $event->getMessage();
        $sender = $message->getSender();

        $this->messageManager->markAsReadByParticipant($message, $sender);
        $this->messageManager->saveMessage($message);
    }
}
```

In services.yml:

```
message_send_listener:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\MessageSendSubscriber
    arguments: [@fos_message.message_manager]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Here you can check what events you can subscribe to: 
        https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Event/FOSMessageEvents.php